# Are any two smooth Cauchy surfaces of a globally hyperbolic manifold diffeomorphic?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

Let $(M,g)$ be a globally hyperbolic Lorentzian manifold. It is known that there exists a smooth Cauchy surface $\Sigma\subset M$ and that $M$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}\times\Sigma$. I suspect that any other smooth Cauchy surface $\Sigma'\subset M$ is diffeomorphic to $\Sigma$, and there is a natural candidate for such a diffeomorphism:

For every $x\in \Sigma$ the maximal timelike, futurepointing path $\gamma$ starting at $x$ intersects $\Sigma'$ in exactly one point $\phi(x)$, thus defining a bijection $\phi:\Sigma\to\Sigma'$. But is $\phi$ smooth?

Comment: Look at Lemma 2.2 in http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0306108.pdf?origin=publication_detail It essentially follows from the existence of a smooth complete timelike vector field on your time-oriented spacetime.